# IMPORTED library that sets linker search directories only

Tags: c++, cmake, pragma

The project I am working on has numerous external dependencies that I am now converting to proper `IMPORTED` targets with their `IMPORTED_LOCATION` or `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` set, along with their `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`. This is much cleaner than just adding all directories to each target globally as it was before.

I'm running into a problem that there is now a library that defines the library that needs to be linked in the source file using a MSVC-specific `#pragma`. I tried adding an `MODULE IMPORTED` library, but that results in `NAME-NOTFOUND.obj` being linked, which is not what I want and not what the documentation seems to imply.

I also tried CMake 3.x's `INTERFACE IMPORTED` library type, which results in the `#pragma`-defined library being linked, but not found, because I found no way to specify the linker search directory for that target. I would prefer a solution that works for CMake 2.8.12.1.

Is there a way to solve this without naming the exact library file in the CMake script?